# Inputting Data back into preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I have a string.

```
$url = 'http://alarms.internal/image?host=database1&srv=IO_Recieved&view=1&source=0&start={TSTAMP:NOW-2D}&end={TSTAMP:NOW}';
```

Looking at the url, I want to grab a few wildcards out of it (Anything that is within curly brackets '{') , and perform some functions on them. Thus I have some regex inserted to pull them out.

```
preg_match_all('/\{[^}]*\}/', $url, $result);
```

This will return to me the following in an array...

```
array(2) 
{ 
    [0]=> string(21) "{TSTAMP:NOW-2D}" 
    [1]=> string(18) "{TSTAMP:NOW}" 
}
```

This is all fine and dandy and nature's candy, however I am curious how I would go about inserting return values back into the original string. For example I might run some code below...

```
function timeConversion($string) {
     ...
     ...

     return $time;

}

$result1 = $result[0][0];
$result2 = $result[0][1];

$time1 = timeConversion($result1);
$time2 = timeConversion($result2);
```

After I have those 2 modified variables, I would like a way of being able to get my initial string to look like the following...

```
echo $url;
```

Which returns...

```
$url = 'http://alarms.internal/image?host=database1&srv=IO_Recieved&view=1&source=0&start=TIME10-45-25DATE10-02-2015&end=TIME10-45-25DATE12-02-2015';
```

Sorry if this is hard to understand, but any help would be great as to how this would be possible.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to do this instead. By using a callback, you can pass any function to it or modify the return values directly inside of the callback.

Below is an example implementation:

```
$url = preg_replace_callback('~{[^}]*}~', 
     function($m) {
        return timeConversion($m[0]);
     }, $url);

echo $url;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Cheers